# how to properly create a simple circular progressbar via css

Tags: css

The code below shows a progressbar with its percent (2%) reading. I need to convert it to a circular progressbar. Can someone help me out?

**Here is the code**

```css
#progress_e {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#bar_e {
  width: 3%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transition: width 700ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress_e">
  <div id="bar_e">
    <div>3%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are dozens of questions on circular progress indicators on SO. I suggest you perform a proper search first.

Comment: [This search should get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=circular+progress+bar+%5Bcss%5D)...

Comment: This one has a lot of samples. https://codepen.io/vikassingh1111/pen/awKjeB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Live example:

```css
body,
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.progress-circle {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* so that children can be absolutely positioned */
  padding: 0;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #F2E9E1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:after {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.35em;
  left: 0.35em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4.3em;
  height: 4.3em;
  background-color: white;
  content: " ";
}


/* Text inside the control */

.progress-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #53777A;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left-half-clipper {
  /* a round circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  /* needed for clipping */
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  /* clips the whole left half*/
}


/* when p>50, don't clip left half*/

.progress-circle.over50 .left-half-clipper {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}

.value-bar {
  /*This is an overlayed square, that is made round with the border radius,
   then it is cut to display only the left half, then rotated clockwise
   to escape the outer clipping path.*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 2.5em, 5em, 0);
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.45em solid #53777A;
  /*The border is 0.35 but making it larger removes visual artifacts */
  /*background-color: #4D642D;*/
  /* for debug */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Progress bar filling the whole right half for values above 50% */

.progress-circle.over50 .first50-bar {
  /*Progress bar for the first 50%, filling the whole right half*/
  position: absolute;
  /*needed for clipping*/
  clip: rect(0, 5em, 5em, 2.5em);
  background-color: #53777A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
}

.progress-circle:not(.over50) .first50-bar {
  display: none;
}


/* Progress bar rotation position */

.progress-circle.p0 .value-bar {
  display: none;
}

.progress-circle.p1 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(4deg);
}

.progress-circle.p2 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.progress-circle.p3 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(11deg);
}

.progress-circle.p4 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(14deg);
}

.progress-circle.p5 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}

.progress-circle.p6 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(22deg);
}

.progress-circle.p7 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.progress-circle.p8 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(29deg);
}

.progress-circle.p9 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(32deg);
}

.progress-circle.p10 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.progress-circle.p11 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.progress-circle.p12 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(43deg);
}

.progress-circle.p13 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(47deg);
}

.progress-circle.p14 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}

.progress-circle.p15 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}

.progress-circle.p16 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(58deg);
}

.progress-circle.p17 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(61deg);
}

.progress-circle.p18 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}

.progress-circle.p19 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(68deg);
}

.progress-circle.p20 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.progress-circle.p21 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(76deg);
}

.progress-circle.p22 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(79deg);
}

.progress-circle.p23 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(83deg);
}

.progress-circle.p24 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(86deg);
}

.progress-circle.p25 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.progress-circle.p26 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(94deg);
}

.progress-circle.p27 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(97deg);
}

.progress-circle.p28 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(101deg);
}

.progress-circle.p29 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(104deg);
}

.progress-circle.p30 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.progress-circle.p31 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(112deg);
}

.progress-circle.p32 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(115deg);
}

.progress-circle.p33 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(119deg);
}

.progress-circle.p34 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(122deg);
}

.progress-circle.p35 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}

.progress-circle.p36 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(130deg);
}

.progress-circle.p37 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(133deg);
}

.progress-circle.p38 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(137deg);
}

.progress-circle.p39 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(140deg);
}

.progress-circle.p40 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.progress-circle.p41 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(148deg);
}

.progress-circle.p42 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(151deg);
}

.progress-circle.p43 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(155deg);
}

.progress-circle.p44 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(158deg);
}

.progress-circle.p45 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}

.progress-circle.p46 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(166deg);
}

.progress-circle.p47 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(169deg);
}

.progress-circle.p48 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(173deg);
}

.progress-circle.p49 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(176deg);
}

.progress-circle.p50 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progress-circle.p51 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(184deg);
}

.progress-circle.p52 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(187deg);
}

.progress-circle.p53 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(191deg);
}

.progress-circle.p54 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(194deg);
}

.progress-circle.p55 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(198deg);
}

.progress-circle.p56 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(202deg);
}

.progress-circle.p57 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(205deg);
}

.progress-circle.p58 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(209deg);
}

.progress-circle.p59 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(212deg);
}

.progress-circle.p60 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}

.progress-circle.p61 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

.progress-circle.p62 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(223deg);
}

.progress-circle.p63 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
}

.progress-circle.p64 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(230deg);
}

.progress-circle.p65 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(234deg);
}

.progress-circle.p66 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(238deg);
}

.progress-circle.p67 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(241deg);
}

.progress-circle.p68 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(245deg);
}

.progress-circle.p69 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(248deg);
}

.progress-circle.p70 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}

.progress-circle.p71 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(256deg);
}

.progress-circle.p72 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(259deg);
}

.progress-circle.p73 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(263deg);
}

.progress-circle.p74 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(266deg);
}

.progress-circle.p75 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.progress-circle.p76 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(274deg);
}

.progress-circle.p77 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(277deg);
}

.progress-circle.p78 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(281deg);
}

.progress-circle.p79 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(284deg);
}

.progress-circle.p80 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}

.progress-circle.p81 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(292deg);
}

.progress-circle.p82 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(295deg);
}

.progress-circle.p83 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(299deg);
}

.progress-circle.p84 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(302deg);
}

.progress-circle.p85 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(306deg);
}

.progress-circle.p86 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(310deg);
}

.progress-circle.p87 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(313deg);
}

.progress-circle.p88 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(317deg);
}

.progress-circle.p89 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(320deg);
}

.progress-circle.p90 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}

.progress-circle.p91 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(328deg);
}

.progress-circle.p92 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(331deg);
}

.progress-circle.p93 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(335deg);
}

.progress-circle.p94 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(338deg);
}

.progress-circle.p95 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(342deg);
}

.progress-circle.p96 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(346deg);
}

.progress-circle.p97 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(349deg);
}

.progress-circle.p98 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(353deg);
}

.progress-circle.p99 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(356deg);
}

.progress-circle.p100 .value-bar {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-circle p2">
  <span>2%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle p8">
  <span>8%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle p13">
  <span>13%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle p26">
  <span>26%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p69">
  <span>69%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-circle over50 p100">
  <span>100%</span>
  <div class="left-half-clipper">
    <div class="first50-bar"></div>
    <div class="value-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Reference:

- https://www.cssscript.com/circular-progress-bar-plain-html-css/
- https://www.digitaldesignjournal.com/best-circular-progress-bar-html-css/